# Is it possible to integrate Levenberg-Marquardt optimizer from Tensorflow Graphics with a Tensorflow 2.0 model?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a Tensorflow 2.0 `tf.keras.Sequential` model. Now, my technical specification prescribes using the Levenberg-Marquardt optimizer to fit the model. Tensorflow 2.0 doesn't provide it as an optimizer out of the box, but it is available in the [Tensorflow Graphics](https://www.tensorflow.org/graphics/api_docs/python/tfg/math/optimizer/levenberg_marquardt) module.

`tfg.math.optimizer.levenberg_marquardt.minimize` function accepts `residuals` ( a residual is a Python `callable` returning a tensor) and `variables` (list of tensors corresponding to my model weights) as parameters.

What would be the best way to convert my model into residuals and variables?

If I understand correctly how the `minimize` function works, I have to provide two residuals. The first residual must call my model for every learning case and aggregate all the results into a tensor. The second residuals must return all labels as a single constant tensor. The problem is that `tf.keras.Sequential.predict` function returns a numpy array instead of tensor. I believe that if I convert it to a tensor, the minimizer won't be able to calculate jacobians with respect to variables.

The same problem is with variables. It doesn't seem like there's a way to extract all weights from a model into a list of tensors.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do so? I am trying to achieve similar thing. I am trying to train a shallow neural net (which on matlab uses Levenberg-Marquardt and does amazingly well). However, the same system trained using ADAM on Keras does awful.

Comment: @psimeson, not really. I ended up hardcoding the formula. Now, whenever the model changes I would have to change the formula accordingly.

Comment: hey @psimeson do you have any news on this? I'm stucked on same issue: converting old matlab script to keras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a major difference between `tfg.math.optimizer.levenberg_marquardt.minimize` and Keras optimizers from the implementation/API perspective.

Keras optimizers, such as `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam` consume gradients as input and updates `tf.Variable`s.

In contrast, `tfg.math.optimizer.levenberg_marquardt.minimize` essentially unrolls the optimization loop in graph mode (using a `tf.while_loop` construct). It takes initial parameter values and produces updated parameter values, unlike Adam & co, which only apply one iteration and actually change the values of `tf.Variable`s via `assign_add`.

Stepping back a bit to the theoretical big picture, Levenberg-Marquardt is not a general gradient descent-like solver for any nonlinear optimization problem (such as Adam is). It specifically addresses *nonlinear least-squares* optimization, so it's not a drop-in replacement for optimizers like Adam. In gradient descent, we compute the gradient of the loss with respect to the parameters. In Levenberg-Marquardt, we compute the Jacobian of the residuals with respect to the parameters. Concretely, it repeatedly solves the linearized problem `Jacobian @ delta_params = residuals` for `delta_params` using `tf.linalg.lstsq` (which internally uses Cholesky decomposition on the Gram matrix computed from the Jacobian) and applies `delta_params` as the update.

Note that this `lstsq` operation has cubic complexity in the number of parameters, so in case of neural nets it can only be applied for fairly small ones.

Also note that Levenberg-Marquardt is usually applied as a *batch algorithm*, not a minibatch algorithm like SGD, though there's nothing stopping you from applying the LM iteration on different minibatches in each iteration.

I think you may only be able to get one iteration out of tfg's LM algorithm, through something like

```py
from tensorflow_graphics.math.optimizer.levenberg_marquardt import minimize as lm_minimize

for input_batch, target_batch in dataset:

    def residual_fn(trainable_params):
        # do not use trainable params, it will still be at its initial value, since we only do one iteration of Levenberg Marquardt each time.
        return model(input_batch) - target_batch

    new_objective_value, new_params = lm_minimize(residual_fn, model.trainable_variables, max_iter=1)
    for var, new_param in zip(model.trainable_variables, new_params):
        var.assign(new_param)
```

In contrast, I believe the following naive method **will not work** where we assign model parameters before computing the residuals:

```py
from tensorflow_graphics.math.optimizer.levenberg_marquardt import minimize as lm_minimize

dataset_iterator = ...

def residual_fn(params):
    input_batch, target_batch = next(dataset_iterator)
    for var, param in zip(model.trainable_variables, params):
        var.assign(param)
    return model(input_batch) - target_batch

final_objective, final_params = lm_minimize(residual_fn, model.trainable_variables, max_iter=10000)
for var, final_param in zip(model.trainable_variables, final_params):
    var.assign(final_param)
```

The main conceptual problem is that `residual_fn`'s output has no gradients wrt its input `params`, since this dependency goes through a `tf.assign`. But it might even fail before that due to using constructs that are disallowed in graph mode.

Overall I believe it's best to write your own LM optimizer that works on `tf.Variables`, since `tfg.math.optimizer.levenberg_marquardt.minimize` has a very different API that is not really suited for optimizing Keras model parameters since you can't directly compute `model(input, parameters) - target_value` without a `tf.assign`.

Comment: There is the same problem with Tensorflow Probability LBFGS. An interface has been done to train neural networks. Maybe some ideas can be used from [here](https://github.com/lululxvi/deepxde/blob/master/deepxde/optimizers/tensorflow/tfp_optimizer.py)